# form submit action="directory/file.php" path doesn't on server error

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which is:

```
<form action="Code Files/file.php" method="post">

<button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</big></button>
</form>
```

Now the problem is when i place the "file.php" in the same folder then form is submitting but when i put in another directory like "Code Files/file.php" its giving error. I tried so many times with different combinations but its not working for me. any help would be appreciated.

tried:

```
../../Code Files/file.php
Code Files/file.php
/Code Files/file.php
```

Directory containing the PHP script:

```
www\Users\Operator\Code Files
```

Directory containing the document with the HTML form:

```
www\Users\Operator\
```

Error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Users/Users/Operator/file.php was not found on this server.
```

**Edited**

Comment: What's the current document Url?

Comment: It would help to know what platform this is on.  Regardless, there is a reasonable chance you need to `chmod +x Code\ Files` so that files in that directory are allowed to be served.

Comment: *"its giving error"* — What error?! Why doesn't anybody say what they error is when they ask a question on Stackoverflow?!

Comment: @Quentin, you can tell from the nature of the problem that the error is simply 404.

Comment: general tip: maximum avoid spaces in file name and folder name...

Comment: @haim770 — I could guess, and it might be 404, but if Conspicuous Compiler is right then it could be a 403, or if the problem is dependancies of `file.php` being in the wrong (relative) place then it could be 500.

Comment: @ Quentin: i posted the error above

Comment: Does your code really say `file.php`? If so, it is odd that the error complains about `FIR Form.php`

Comment: @Quentin that was my mistake sorry.

Comment: By "document url" and "Cureent document url", do you mean "The directory containing the script you are trying to reference in the action" and "The directory containing the page with the HTML form"?

Comment: If you have `action="Code Files/file.php"` but the error message doesn't mention `Code Files` at all, then you probably have some unfortunate interaction with a `mod_rewrite` or `Alias` directive in your Apache configuration (or the equivalent in whatever other HTTP server you are using).

Comment: @Quentin:  
By "document url" and "Cureent document url", do you mean "The directory containing the script you are trying to reference in the action" and "The directory containing the page with the HTML form"?

Yes

Comment: any solution to that??

Comment: Find the relevant part of the configuration and change it.

Comment: lets try to understand the question, what you say is that you have a file (file.php), with a form, and depending on the value of the action on that form the submit action works or doesn't work? is that what is happening?

Comment: through my form file which is "Form.php" i want to goto the php file which is "file.php" through action="Code Files/file.php" in my form file

Answer (score 0):

Try **not** to use whitespaces in your pathnames and filenames. Also consider that pathnames and filenames on operating systems like Linux are case-sensitive so File.php != file.php